# RDLC fixing a table row bottom at footer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, rdlc

I am using VS 2015 C#, got a RDLC. In it I put table and repeats header row and footer row at every page. Problem is I want to fix footer row at bottom of page. I found some solutions counting rows and breaking space etc but I can't apply them VS2015, and some of the codes was visual basic.

Here is how it looks ;

[image]

Here is how I want ;

[image]

Comment: What kind of data do you want to have in the footer? If this is something you can pass as parameters? in this case, maybe you should consider putting in it in actual report footer.

Comment: @InitK yes but can't add matrix to report footer ?

Comment: ah, yes, you cannot do anything with dataset in the footer.